# Resolvent from solution of differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone maybe explain how to go from the solution of the system of differential equations to the resolvent $P(t,t_0)$ with $t_0=0$? The image below shows the answer from the Student's Manual.

[image: Answer From Student's Manual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got $x(t)=U(t)C$. From comparing with this same parametrization at time $t=t_0$ you get $C=U(t_0)^{-1}x(t_0)$, so that in combination
$$
x(t)=P(t,t_0)x(t_0)=U(t)U(t_0)^{-1}x(t_0),\\
P(t,t_0)=U(t)U(t_0)^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Is such $P$ called resolvent? (That is what I call a two parameter family)

Comment: If you say it is, then it is. Another common name is "propagator", as it propagates the state at $t_0$ to the state at $t$. More commonly "resolvent" is found at $R(\lambda)=(I-\lambda A)^{-1}$ or similar in spectral theory of operators, endomorphisms, on Banach spaces.

Comment: Yes that was precisely my point. I've heard such an object called propagator, evolution operator, two parameter family of evolution operator, but never resolvent. While I'm familiar with your (or similar) definition of resolvent in spectral theory (introduced I believe by Fredholm among others). Do you know why such object should be called resolvent?

Comment: For time independent problems the resolvent ($(A-z)^{-1}$) and the propagator ($(e^{tA}$) are the Laplace transform one of each other. Which is one more reason  to give the two objects different names.

Comment: I don't know, one could speculate that as it produces a solution,... Another name for $P(t,0)$ is of course "fundamental matrix".

Comment: Thanks  (and then I have to add smth)

Comment: Could maybe one of you demonstrate how the first element of $P(t,0)$ is formed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have $U(t)=V·diag(e^{λt})$, so you get $P(t,0)=V·diag(e^{λt})·V^{-1}$, where the columns of $V$ are the eigenvectors in the solution formula. There is no way to get the first element independent of the others, you need to invert a matrix resp. solve some linear systems.